# Adding a redirect to a Web Control / HTML Writer

Tags: c#, html

I am creating a dynamic navigation, with a for loop putting each record in the database into a button. However i want to add redirect to buttons so when it is clicked it directs to a page passing an ID over. How can i make the buttons redirect??

The html writer tag for the button is as follows ::

```
writer.RenderBeginTag(tag.Button);
```

Comment: Why not making an hyperlink ? (you could style it to look like a button)

Comment: i need to keep consistency from buttons used previously in the site, i can style them like the html buttons but it is not the same. So i need to use the html buttons and find a way to have them redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use HTML button (I guess < input type='button'>), then you can only interact with them using javascript.
You should use

```
window.location = url
```

And build url to contain your id :

```
http://mysite/myPage?Id=12
```

Then you may pass Id using data attributes. For example :

```
<input type='button' data-id="12"/>
```

then, in JS, if using jquery :

```
var btn = ...get-your-button-by-id-or-class-name-or-whatever
var id = btn.data('id');
window.location='http://mysite/myPage?Id='+id;
```